# succesor in binary tree

Tags: java, binary-search-tree

```
class ElemDrzewa<T extends Comparable<T>>{

    final T elem;
    ElemDrzewa<T> lewy;
    ElemDrzewa<T> prawy;
    ElemDrzewa<T> rodzic;
    ElemDrzewa(T elem)
    {
        this.elem = elem;
        lewy = null;
        prawy = null;
    }


}

public class Drzewo<T extends Comparable<T>>{

    private ElemDrzewa<T> korzen;
    public Drzewo(){

        korzen = null;

    }

    public ElemDrzewa<T> search(T elem){

        ElemDrzewa<T> actual = korzen;
        while(actual!=null && actual.elem != elem)
            if(actual.elem.compareTo(elem)>0) actual = actual.lewy;
            else actual = actual.prawy;

            return actual;

    }

    private ElemDrzewa<T> min(ElemDrzewa<T> w){

        while(w.lewy != null)
        w = w.lewy;
        return w;
    }

    private ElemDrzewa<T> max(ElemDrzewa<T> w){

        while(w.prawy != null)
        w = w.prawy;
        return w;
    }

    private ElemDrzewa<T> nast(ElemDrzewa<T> w){

        if(w.prawy != null) return min(w.prawy);

        ElemDrzewa<T> tmp = w.rodzic;

        while(w!=null && w.lewy!= tmp)
        w = tmp;
        tmp = tmp.rodzic;
        return tmp;
    }

    private ElemDrzewa<T> poprz(ElemDrzewa<T> w){

        if(w.lewy != null) return max(w.lewy);

        ElemDrzewa<T> tmp = w.rodzic;

        while(w!=null && w.prawy!= tmp)
        w = tmp;
        tmp = tmp.rodzic;
        return tmp;
    }

    public ElemDrzewa<T> del(T elem){

        ElemDrzewa<T> w = this.search(elem);
        ElemDrzewa<T> rodzic = w.rodzic;
        ElemDrzewa<T> tmp;

        if(w.lewy!=null && w.prawy!=null){

            tmp = this.del(this.nast(elem).elem);
            tmp.lewy = w.lewy;
            if(tmp.lewy!=null)
            tmp.lewy.rodzic = tmp;
            tmp.prawy = w.prawy;
            if(tmp.prawy!=null)
            tmp.prawy.rodzic = tmp;
        }

        else{
            if(w.lewy!=null)    tmp = w.lewy;
            else tmp = w.prawy;
        }
        if(tmp!=null)   tmp.rodzic = rodzic;
        if(rodzic == null) korzen = tmp;
        else if(rodzic.lewy == w) rodzic.lewy = tmp;
        else rodzic.prawy = tmp;

        return w;
    }

}
```

this is my code and i have problem with private `ElemDrzewa<T> nast(ElemDrzewa<T> w)`

the error is `nast(ElemDrzewa<T>) in Drzewo<T> cannot be applied to (T)`
the min is to look for minimal value, max for maximal value, nast for find succesor, poprz for find predecesor

Comment: Are those supposed to be `class ElemDrzewa<T>` and `public class Drzewo<T>`?  Or should the extra `>` characters be removed?  I tried it the first way and I think I'm getting errors in different locations than you're getting.

Comment: For anyone else reading this: drzewo=tree, lewy=left, prawy=right, rodzic=father, korzen=root, nast=next

Answer (score 0):

You can't call `this.nast(ElemDrzewa<T> w)` in method `del` with argument `elem`, because `elem` is of type `T` and `T` does not extend `ElemDrzewa<T>`.

Answer (score 0):

This line:

```
    if(actual.elem.compareTo(elem)>0) actual = actual.lewy;
```

will not compile, because `actual.elem` has type `T`, and the compiler doesn't know anything about `T`.  Not all `Object`s have `compareTo` methods; for this to work, the compiler needs to know that `T` implements `Comparable`.  If that's your intent, that you can use this class only with a type that implements `Comparable`, change the first line to

```
public class Drzewo<T extends Comparable<T>> {
```

**EDIT:** The original post has now been edited to make the line look like this, but not by the original questioner.  So my answer may or may not be irrelevant.